# Is it possible to create a view for a subquery referring the main query?

Tags: postgresql, subquery, sql-view

If have a query that uses a subquery. Basically it is like this:

```
SELECT A.name, A.pk 
       array_to_string(array(SELECT B.name FROM b WHERE B.relA  = A.pk ),', ')    
FROM A;
```

Basically it makes a column in `A` from a to-many relationship to `B`. (In my case `A` is a list of items and `B` contains tags related to that items. The query makes a column with a list of tags for each row in `A`.)

Since the real world query is more complex and I need the subquery more than one time, I want to make a view from the subquery (DRY). This is not possible, because `A.pk` is only known, if the subquery *is* a subquery in a main query that fetches from `A`. It is not known if the subquery stands alone. So I cannot create a view from the stand-alone version:

```
CREATE VIEW bview AS SELECT B.b FROM B WHERE B.relA=A.pk;
```

gives me the expected:

```
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "A"
```

Is there a way to define akin of "incomplete view", that is not executed itself, but in a main query completing the subquery without using functions?

Edit: The `WHERE` clause inside the subquery cannot be replaced with a `JOIN` clause, because it takes the `A.pk` from the outer query.

Comment: Or you can use CREATE VIEW bview AS SELECT A.pk, B.b FROM B JOIN A ON B.relA = A.pk; And it: `SELECT * FROM bview WHERE <where clause>`

Comment: @RomanTkachuk This is not the same, because it creates a new relaltion in the subquery. But it should take the `A.pk` from the main query. I added n explanation to the Q.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a simple view without referring to table `A` and then use that as a row source in various parts of your complex query:

```
CREATE VIEW bview AS
    SELECT relA, string_agg(name, ', ') AS tags
    FROM b
    GROUP BY relA;
```

This may seem inefficient because if you run the view like this without qualification, then all tags for all `relA` are concatenated. However, when you use the view in a larger query with qualifications, then the view is only evaluated for those `relA` values that are asked for in the outer query. This is because [the view is "merged" with the outer query by the planner](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rules-views.html).

So you end up with:

```
SELECT name, pk, tags
FROM A
JOIN bview ON relA = pk;
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach. I'll give it a try and report the result.